# Does Ionic 3 Barcode Scanning support GS1-128 barcode format?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

I am currently making an application, with the use of Ionic 3, that can scan GS1-128 barcode format. I tested several barcodes, it worked. But, in GS1-128 format, parenthesis are removed.

I hope there's someone to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the parenthesis at the start of the barcode, they are never encoded.  They're present in the human-readable part under the barcode so humans can see the AI quickly.  But they are not part of the GS1-128 barcode -- unless they're used in the payload after the AI (and that's pretty rare, I've found).  What you should be looking for (when you scan the barcode) is the FNC1 code that defines the next characters as an AI.  See section 5.4 of the [GS1 manual](https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes-epcrfid-id-keys/gs1-general-specifications) for code128 barcode details, and section 4.15 for the Human readable part.  Specifically, rule 3:

> Rule 3. Parentheses SHALL surround AIs in HRI [Human readable interpretation] but are not encoded in the GS1 AIDC [automatic identification and data capture] data carrier.

You'll need to look up the AI in a table (there's one in section 3.2) to see how long it should be and if additional data follows (like an expiration date) before you can pull out the actual data.